# Android. Check checkbox in another activity when receive SMS

Tags: android, android-activity, checkbox, sms

(Sorry for my english)
I got a Picdem.net2 dev card with a telit gt864-quad modem GSM. When there is a problem with the things connected to the dev card (for example a problem with the water controller), the dev card send a sms to my android phone, to prevent me.

When the sms is coming, it should show a notification, and check a "alert" checkbox in an other Activity named "etat" (state).
The SMS activity is named "SMSReceive".

So actually I can recept the SMS and it bring an alert notification, who leads to the app if I click on it. But I don't know how to check the checkbox...

(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id. ...) doesn't work.

```
package com.example.locatiris;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class SMSReceive extends BroadcastReceiver
{
CheckBox water = null;
private static final int Notification_ID = 1234;
private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";


    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {


    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    //SMS pdus = format de SMS
    Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

    for(int i=0; i<smsMessage.length; i++)
    {
        smsMessage[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])messages[i]);
        //récupérer le numéro
     String msg_from = smsMessage[i].getOriginatingAddress();
     //Récuperer message
     String msg_cont = smsMessage[i].getMessageBody();

        if(msg_from.equals("+33NUMBER") & msg_cont.contains("water"))
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
            "Message reçu " + smsMessage[0].getMessageBody(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
             //faire une action lors de réception
            createNotification(context);

        }                    
    }
}

}
```

Here is how start "etat" activity :

```
public class etat extends Activity// implements View.OnClickListener
{
EditText Chau = null;
EditText Vann = null;
EditText Serr = null;
EditText Digi = null;
Button Actu = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ ...
```

Here are the Notification Creator :

```
private final void createNotification(Context context2)
{
    //vibreur spécial
    long[] a = {0, 200, 200, 200, 500, 200, 500, 200, 200, 500, 200 };

    //creer notification et ses parametres
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =  
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context2)  
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setTicker("Problème location détecté")
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setVibrate(a)
    .setSound(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Music/ZOUZ2.mp3"))
    .setContentTitle("ALERTE Location")
    .setContentText("Un problème est survenu dans la location");

    //ouvrir l'application au clic sur notification
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context2, MainActivity.class);  
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context2, 0, notificationIntent,   
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);  

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context2.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  
    manager.notify(Notification_ID, builder.build());  
}
```

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following code  on notification click to invoke activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, etat.class);
intent.putExtra("isSMSReceived", true/false);
startactivity(intent)
```

in your activity use this code

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
boolean state = intent.getBooleanExtra("isSMSReceived");

CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id. ...);
cb.setChecked(state);
```

Comment: Yes I understand how work your code now, but I try to correct errors that are happening

Comment: I put the Notification Creator in the first post. My errors are : ***Intent(SMSReceive, class <etat>) is undefinded***
and also ***The method startactivity(Intent) is undefined for the type SMSReceive***
And for the other activity :
***The method getBooleanExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String)***

Comment: I adapted the code, but the problem is that my notification go to a "login" activity, not the etat activity. So I put the second code into the "login" activity, it doesn't say there are errors but the app force close at start. Also, if I must add a bool in the method getBooleanExtra("isSMSReceived",***true***)

Comment: But anyway thanks for your answer ! it seems that I can't go to the activity where there are your second code. I think that it's getIntent() who cause the force close but I m not sure. In the logcat I can see : Caused by : java.lang.nullpointerexception

Comment: So, nobody know what can be the problem ? Thanks !

Comment: what us SMSReceive in ur  Intent(SMSReceive, class <etat>)

Comment: SMSReceive is the name of the class where there is your "first" code, it is "context2"

Comment: Here is the code from my SMSReceive activity for the notification : ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// `Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context2, etat.class);  
        notificationIntent.putExtra("isSMSReceived", true); //////////////////////////

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context2, 0, notificationIntent,   
             PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); ///////////////////// 
     builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);`

Comment: why dont you create a static context in your main class and use it to invoke a intent

Comment: Yes. There was a mistake in a command line in my second activity where there are the checkbox. But I resolve it ! Thanks.